# GSON: Using fromJson to convert a list of dictionaries

Tags: java, json, rest, api, gson

I am currently trying to extract the name 'Best I Ever Had' from the last.fm API shown below using GSON but having difficulty with it constantly returning a null value.

******************************EDIT*****************************

Here is the JSON, with tracks being a list of dictionaries, one for each song name:

```
{
toptracks: {
   track: [
        {
          name: "Best I Ever Had"
        }
   ]
}
}
```

Using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ I have created the following classes:

TrackName.java

```
package com.webservice1;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class TrackName {

@SerializedName("toptracks")
@Expose
private Toptracks toptracks;

public Toptracks getToptracks() {
    return toptracks;
}

public void setToptracks(Toptracks toptracks) {
    this.toptracks = toptracks;
}

public TrackName withToptracks(Toptracks toptracks) {
    this.toptracks = toptracks;
    return this;
}

}
```

Toptracks.java

```
package com.webservice1;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Toptracks {

@SerializedName("track")
@Expose
private List<Track> track = null;

public List<Track> getTrack() {
    return track;
}

public void setTrack(List<Track> track) {
    this.track = track;
}

public Toptracks withTrack(List<Track> track) {
    this.track = track;
    return this;
}

}
```

and finally Track.java

```
package com.webservice1;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Track {

@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Track withName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

}
```

And here is my code using fromJson method where reply contains the whole JSON and is constantly 'Track Name com.webservice1.Toptracks@1b9e1916'

```
        String reply;

        reply = reader.readLine();

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        TrackName response = gson.fromJson(reply, TrackName.class);

        System.out.println("Track Name " + response.getToptracks());
```

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Well, PopularTrack doesn't match the structure of your JSON object at all. The JSON object has a property named toptracks, which is an object with a property named track, which is an array of objects having a name property. PopularTrack doesn't match that at all. It just has a name. So it could be used to map a JSON looking like `{ "name": "foo" }`.

Comment: Can use http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/ to generate propper object structure

Comment: How do I go about creating a class which matches my JSON Object?

Comment: The JSON has a toptracks property. So you need that in your top-level class. Its value is an object in the JSON. So you create another class to model this object. The toptracks JSON object has an array named track. So you add a track property to this second class. The array contains objects. So you create a third class to model this third kind of JSON object.

Comment: Please see edited code using http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. My problem now is that it is not outputting 'Best I Ever Had'. Do you know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Well, you're printing the TopTracks object, which doesn't have any toString() method. So the default implementation, inherited from Object, is used. It prints the class name followed by the hashCode of the object. If you want to write the name of the first of the tracks, you need `response.getToptracks().getTrack().get(0).getName()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) and I'm sure there are settings to ignore missing fields etc...

Here is the maven dependency for the library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.2</version>
</dependency>
```

---

```
    String json = "{\n"
            + "  \"toptracks\" : {\n"
            + " \"track\": [{\n"
            + "     \"name\": \"Best I Ever Had\",\n"
            + "     \"playcount\": \"3551414\",\n"
            + "     \"listeners\": \"1058277\",\n"
            + "     \"mbid\": \"00bde944-7562-446f-ad0f-3d4bdc86b69f\",\n"
            + "     \"url\": \"https://www.last.fm/music/Drake/_/Best+I+Ever+Had\",\n"
            + "     \"streamable\": \"0\",\n"
            + "     \"artist\": {\n"
            + "         \"name\": \"Drake\",\n"
            + "         \"mbid\": \"b49b81cc-d5b7-4bdd-aadb-385df8de69a6\",\n"
            + "         \"url\": \"https://www.last.fm/music/Drake\"\n"
            + "     }\n"
            + " }]\n"
            + "}\n"
            + "}";

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    TopTracks track = mapper.readValue(json, TopTracks.class);

    List<Object> trackList = (List<Object>)track.toptracks.get("track");

    Map<String, Object> trackMap = (Map<String, Object>) trackList.get(0);

    System.out.println(trackMap.get("name"));

public class TopTracks {

    public Map<String, Object> toptracks = new HashMap<>();
}
```

Output:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ MVN ---
Best I Ever Had
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD SUCCESS
```